# typescript problem with jquery type definition

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, global-variables, typescript-typings

I use Angular 9 universal, Typescript version ~3.7.5 and I installed both jQuery and its type definition using:

```
npm i jquery npm i @types/jquery
```

Then I added jQuery in the types field in the tsconfig file. However after I run the app I still get this error:

> Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try "npm i @types/jquery" and then add "jquery" to the types field in your tsconfig.`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you ran `npm i jquery npm i @types/jquery` this in one line or one after another.

Answer (score 1):

**Install jQuery**

`npm install --save jquery`

**Install jQuery Definition**

`npm install -D @types/jquery`

**than include jquery in a component like this**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Example:

```
$(selector).hide();
```

**OR**

`declare var jQuery: any;`

Example:

```
jQuery(selector).hide();
```

Comment: How do you know about defining a $ variable? there is no source for it.

Comment: I tried it, and there was no error at compile time but there is one at runtime: ` core.js:5871 ERROR TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: @roya Which solution first or second? If first then please replace “$” with “jQuery” in the script. I had the same error and fixed it or try with the second solution.

Comment: Depending on https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries, I added the associated script and css files to the "scripts" and "styles" array in angular.json. then i used $("p").tooltip();

Comment: Please check this link: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-install-and-use-jquery-in-angular-projects/

Comment: I checked your reference, when i use `declare var jQuery: any;` there is an error when i run the app and i think it is on ssr time. or maybe not. because when i use another way `import * as $ from 'jquery';` and remove jquery file reference in angular.json, i don't see that error but i see another error at run time that says bootstrap needs jquery, cause i used bootstrap.